# Heroku Console and New Relic (cedar stack)

Tags: heroku, newrelic

My team is continuously getting New Relic log messages on our heroku console.  This highly annoying and causes issues when your working on a longer command, and a batch of new relic log messages prints out over your command.

Anyone else have this?  Any direction on how to remedy?

Comment: i have also seen these logging messages ... they have start appearing after getting upgrade the heroku cli version. Well i think you should add a ticket to heroku to make them turn off .... but as the one-off-process associate gets charged so its the  default behavior so hopefully they will provide some option to hide them on one-off-process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your log level setting in your newrelic.yml config file.  The log level can be altered the same as any other logging (fatal, warning, debug etc)

Comment: Actually, it still appears to show some output.  Changing to 'error' did the trick.